# How to insert a date in mysql via php?

Tags: php, mysql

i have date in a variable as

```
 $d = 2014-MAR-20;
```

How to insert this `$d` value to a field having type 'Date' in mysql using php?.

Comment: You should use `DATE` type for column where valid format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: He does use the "DATE" column in Mysql "field having type 'Date' in mysql"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$d=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($d));
```

Then insert it to your table with your date column.

```
mysqli_query($YourConnection,"INSERT INTO yourTable (date) VALUES ('$d')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
  $d = "2014-MAR-20"; 
  $date =date('Y-m-d',strtotime($d)); // convert to Mysql format
```

Insert date value using PDO prepared statement

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`date`) VALUES(?)");
  $stmt->execute(array($date));
```